# Locating UI code not on the platform / dispatch thread

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, javafx, ui-thread

I'm currently attempting to debug a medium scale (in the 10's of thousands of lines ballpark) Java project which uses both JavaFX and Swing, and I'm hitting some odd exceptions every so often which I'm pretty sure are because of UI code not being called on the correct thread. The stack trace for these exceptions isn't really helpful at all, since they pretty much all originate from the UI drawing thread.

Now, sure I could sit down with a toothcomb and debug every UI call until I find one that's not being called on the correct thread, and keep doing that for the entire project, but that would be an incredibly long task. Is there some form of easier way to do this sort of debugging? For instance, somehow cause UI code to print out a debug message or throw an exception when it's not been called from its appropriate thread?

Comment: A. Potochkin has a nice collection of techniques: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2006/02/debugging_swing.html. Using aspectj ruleset is quite effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running JavaFX and Swing on the same thread might help fix your threading issues.

There is an experimental feature in Java 8 to run JavaFX and Swing on the same thread:

https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-30694
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8015477

I think `-Djavafx.embed.singleThread=true` is the command line property setting to enable the experimental single threading system.

I am not sure if the [experimental feature](http://www.mail-archive.com/openjfx-dev@openjdk.java.net/msg01701.html) is available in the [current Java 8 builds](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html), but I think it might be now, so you may wish to try it.

If you need more information on the experimental single threading feature, you could ask the developers on the [openjfx-dev mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev).

---

Java 8 has better inbuilt reporting of when code is not run on the correct thread, it's not comprehensive, but it *might* assist you in locating the source of your error, even if you are not using the single threading option.

---

Some other users running large applications merging Swing and JavaFX reported similar hard to debug threading issues, so you could check those [threads](http://www.mail-archive.com/openjfx-dev@openjdk.java.net/msg01880.html) to see if your issues have the same cause.

Comment: Thanks, Java 8 printed out something that wasn't actually the issue directly, but did lead me to it eventually. FWIW, I really think there needs to be comprehensive built in support of checking when stuff isn't running on the correct thread, even if that's just a debug option you can switch on - even when not combining multiple toolkits it's a very easy mistake to make that can lead to debugging hell later on. Ah well... Java 8 is a step in the right direction at least.

Comment: This is actually a VERY experimental feature. You could try it with the current EA builds from http://jdk8.java.net

Comment: @Petr Sure, I realise that, being part of JDK8 I wouldn't class it as anything less! It did prove useful temporarily running my app alongside Java 8 though just to make use of this feature.

Answer (score 3):

You could turn on thread checks in glass by `-Dglass.disableThreadChecks=false`. This would switch on the thread checks in the lowest layer of JavaFX which is responsible for working with OS level APIs. In most cases those checks would be sufficient, because most of the calls are ending up in Glass. These checks would be enabled by default soon.

Comment: Thanks - a useful option which I've now turned on! Fortunately nothing seems to be printed, I guess that's a good sign. The option seems a weird way round to me - I would have expected something along the lines of `enableThreadChecks=true`!

Comment: This is historical. The thread checks were included unconditionally, but than a lot of threading bugs were found. So the option ti disable the checks was included until the bugs are resolved.